# Add reply to a discussion board topic using jsom

Tags: discussion-board

I am using discussion board as a comment board for my Assets library in SharePoint 2013

I am very well able to retrieve the topic and replies from the discussion board.

What I want is to post a reply to these topics using JSOM.

There is an `AddDiscussionBoardItem` method in C#, is there a JSOM alternative to this?

Answer (score 2):

### How to post a reply in Discussion Board using SharePoint JSOM

Use [SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussionReply(Context, parent) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408981(v=office.14).aspx) to post a reply to a discussion item:

```
function createMessage(discussionItem,properties,OnItemAdded,OnItemError)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var messageItem = SP.Utilities.Utility.createNewDiscussionReply(context, discussionItem);
    for(var propName in properties) {
       messageItem.set_item(propName, properties[propName]) 
    }
    messageItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          OnItemAdded(messageItem);           
        },
        OnItemError
    );
}
```

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Discussion Board');
var discussionItem = list.getItemById(1);   

var messageProperties = {'Body': 'SharePoint 2013 is used in our company'}; 
createMessage(discussionItem,messageProperties,
    function(){
        console.log('Reply has been post successfully');
    },
    function(sender,args){
         console.log('Error occurred while posting a reply:' + args.get_message());
    }
);
```

For a more details please follow [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/01/20/working-with-discussions-list-via-sharepoint-client-object-model/).