# How to create/add discussion board to site using CSOM

Tags: development, discussion-board, csom

Is it possible to add or create a discussion board for a site? Many of the resources I find describe how to add a post to an already existing discussion board, but no mention of how to create one.

Please see: [How to reply to discussion board](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79317/add-reply-to-a-discussion-board-topic-using-jsom)

I have come across the `createNewDiscussion` [utility method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411626(v=office.14).aspx), but it appears to involve passing a list first. Is a discussion board just a list with a different interface?

Is implementing the utility function described above the correct path to take?

Also, please note that I am currently utilizing `CSOM` to communicate with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

A Discussionboard is nothing but a list with the ListTemplateType.DiscussionBoard. 
So yes: This is the correct path. Create a list using the correct type and follow the links you already mentioned.